# Get data row by filter from database and add to datagridview

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

Hi I am trying to read the row of a database .accdb and add it to my datagridview

I am getting this error

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Data.DataRow]' to type
>   'System.Data.DataRow'.

I have tried for hours and no joy.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
            Dim chk = (From dr As DataRow In Test1DataSet.Tables(0).Rows Select dr Where dr("SN:").ToString = "" & SN_TextBox.Text.ToString() & "").Count
            Dim c As Integer
            c = chk
            Try
                Dim aa As DataRow
                aa = (From dr As DataRow In Test1DataSet.Tables(0).Rows Select dr Where dr("SN:").ToString = "" & SN_TextBox.Text.ToString() & "" AndAlso dr("times tested").ToString = c.ToString)
                DataGridView1.Rows.Add(aa)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
aa = (From dr As DataRow...ToString).FirstOrDefault
```

Comment: This is a good start further it is now adding to one cell but only giving me "Test_Data_Logger.Test1DataSet+Test_DataRow" How Can I get the information form this.

Comment: @user1362134: I don't understand your question. Please elaborate more.

Comment: I am adding this data to a unbound datagridview when I click add it is adding only to the first cell "Test_Data_Logger.Test1DataSet+Test_DataRow"   Do I need to have the columns named the same as the DB columns

Comment: @user1362134: Are you saying that `Test1DataSet.Tables(0).Rows` has different columns than `DataGridView1.Rows` ?